# Matlab ode45 is not outputting solutions for each increment specified by my "time-span" vector

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, ode45

I am using the following code to call a function for ODE45 to solve:

```
[outputs]=ode45(@(t,y)ILLYAcoupled(t,y,N,w,g),(0:0.5e-3:50),y0);
```

I am trying to get ode45 to give me values at 0.5e-3 increments between 0 and 50, which should output a solution vector length of about 10000, but I'm getting a solution vector of only 2720 points.
What is weird is that I was calling another function for ode45 to solve in the following fashion:

```
[outputs] = ode45(@HH,(0:0.5e-3:50),y0);
```

...and this was giving me the desired 10000 length solution vector--until recently. I tried calling it in this way:

```
[outputs] = ode45(@(t,y)HH(t,y),(0:0.5e-3:50),y0);
```

...which gave me a 2720 length solution vector and, now, even when I've changed the code back to the "@HH" by itself it keeps giving me the 2720 length vector rather than the desired 10000 length one.

It seems like something in the way I am specifying inputs and outputs to the called function during the ode45 call is messing things up but I don't know what.

I will be super grateful for any advice one might have!! Thanks!

Comment: What is `[outputs]`? Are you abbreviating `[t,y]` or are you using the single output argument option. If it's the latter then you should read the documentation – the single output option only supports an initial and a final time (it appears the others are ignored) and one must use `deval` to interpolate to a particular grid.

Comment: By itself, the fact that the solution does not last as long as you'd like is normal: the solution of a differential equation may cease to exist at some point.

Comment: The issue was that I was using "outputs" rather than breaking the solution down into the "t" and "y" arrays. Thanks a lot for the advice folks!!